# How to covert each sender_id into a user email

Tags: php, laravel

Hello how do I convert each sender_id into a user email.

This are my codes that doesn't work to give you an idea on what i'm doing.

```
$mails = Email::where('recipient_id',Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get();   // GET ALL THE MAILS THAT IS SENT TO                                                                                                                 THE USER....

        $senders = $mails->get()->sender_id;  //GETS ALL THE MAILS SENDER_ID

       foreach ($mails as $mails) {
            $mails->first()->sender_id
            $sender_email = User::where('id', $mails)->first()->email;  // CONVER ALL THE SENDER ID INTO USER EMAIL
        }
```

what I want to happen is

1. get all the sender_id
2. convert the sender_id into their email address
3. send it to the view

> Mail Inbox

```
 @foreach($mails as $mail)
                <tr>
                  <td class="mailbox-name"><a href="#">$EMAIL ADDRESS</a></td>
                  <td class="mailbox-subject"> <b>$mail->subject</b> </td>
                </tr>
    @endforeach
```

I'm doing it wrong and how to do it right please tell me I'm so stupid to make this work I need help!

Comment: How are your tables made up? Is everything inside the emails table? Or is it stored in multiple tables?

Comment: Everything is inside the emails table. and the sender_id in there references
id on users table. and in users table there is email address.
I wanted to convert the sender_id into email address to appear in the mailbox view

Answer (score 1):

In foreach loop, you have put `$mails as $mails` which puts you in trouble. Change the variable name.

Comment: it is actually $mails as $mail.